# Show md-select if other md-select - selected value = concrete_value

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-ng-if, md-select

I have two md-selects:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="someAction(f)" #f="ngForm">
   <md-select
       #selectedHolidayType
        placeholder="Holiday type"
        name="holiday_type"
        [(ngModel)]="holiday_type"
    >
   <md-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.typeId">{{ type.typeName}}</md-option>
   </md-select>

<md-select
     *ngIf="selectedHolidayType === 19"
     placeholder="Some placeholder"
     name="option"
     [ngModel]="option"
>
      <md-option *ngFor="option of options" [value]="option.id">{{option.value}}</md-option>

</md-select>
</form>
```

How can i show second md-select only if first md-select selected value is set to what i want, in this case - 19.

Or maybe : how can i get selected value of first md-select in html template?

I already tried:

```
*ngIf="holiday_type === 19"
*ngIf="selectedHolidayType.selected === 19"
*ngIf="selectedHolidayType.selected.value === 19"
```

But none of that works.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the answer:

```
 <md-select
       #selectedHolidayType
        placeholder="Holiday type"
        name="holiday_type"
        [(ngModel)]="holiday_type"
    >
   <md-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.typeId">{{ type.typeName}}
   </md-option>
</md-select>

<div *ngIf="holiday_type > 0">

    <md-select
     *ngIf="holiday_type == 19"
     placeholder="Some placeholder"
     name="option"
     [ngModel]="option"
    >
      <md-option *ngFor="option of options" [value]="option.id">{{option.value}}
    </md-option>

  </md-select>

</div>
```

No idea why but if i wrap md-select in a div it works!

I would realy apreciate if someone could explain that behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't work when you tried `*ngIf="holiday_type === 19"`.

Here is an [**EXAMPLE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-dekhwa?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) of it working like this,

```
<form>
  <md-select placeholder="Holiday type"
      name="holiday_type"
      [(ngModel)]="holiday_type">
    <md-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type.typeId">{{ type.typeName }}</md-option>
  </md-select>

  <!-- Only show when 19 is selected -->
  <md-select *ngIf="holiday_type === 19"
      placeholder="Some placeholder"
      name="option"
      [(ngModel)]="option">
    <md-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.id">{{ option.value }}</md-option>
  </md-select>

</form>
```

Comment: Dude, i know that it should work like u did in your answer, but it doesn't ;/ no idea why, that's why i posted this question. Did u check it with data from rest api in `*ngFor` ?

Comment: No I didn't. Maybe you can append some of your class code to your original post? Or fork the example in this answer to make it match your situation more clearly?